# os.system() cannot excute my command at the every first time, why?

Tags: python, shell

I use `os.system()` to change the directory by `cd` like follwing in a function:

```
def xxx():
        os.system("cd ../../../../../..")
        print "move dir: "+os.getcwd()
```

Then I use this function in a script for 7 times:

```
def testcase():
    ……
    xxx();
    ……

if __name__=='__main__':
    testcase1()
    testcase2()
    ……
    testcase7()
```

the log shows I only succeeded 6 times,the first time always failed like:

```
move dir: /home/tzhang/luatest/alphaless/.build/experimental_trusty/alphaless/tests/tests.py.rundirs/1

move dir: /home/tzhang/luatest/alphaless

move dir: /home/tzhang/luatest/alphaless

move dir: /home/tzhang/luatest/alphaless

move dir: /home/tzhang/luatest/alphaless

move dir: /home/tzhang/luatest/alphaless

move dir: /home/tzhang/luatest/alphaless
```

> /home/tzhang/luatest/alphaless/.build/experimental_trusty/alphaless/tests/tests.py.rundirs/1

is the position at the beginning of every testcase

What leads to the error?

Comment: Can you provide a [short but complete program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem you're having?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `os.system()`, use `os.chdir()`.

With `os.system()` you are executing a command, but with `os.chdir()` you are changing the current working directory to the given path. For this case, is more apropiated.